# inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation for ask the expert coding

Tags: syntax-error

```
from tkinter import Tk, simpledialog, messagebox

def read_from_file():
    with open('capital_data.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        country, city = line.split('/')
        the_world[country] = city

def write_to_file(' country_name, city_name):
    with open('capital_data.txt,' 'a') as file
    file.write('\n' + country_name + '/' + city_name')

print(' ask the expert - capital city of the world')
root = Tk ()
root.withdraw()
the_world = {}

read_from_file()

while True:
    query_ country = simpledialog.askstring('country', 'type the name of a country:')

    if query_country in the_world:
    result = the_world[query_country]
    messagebox.showinfo ('answer',
                         'The capital city of ' + query_country + ' is ' + result + '!')
    else:
    new_city = simpledialog.askstring('teach me',
                                      'i don\ 't know! ' +
                                      'what is the capital of ' +     query_country + '?')
    the_world[query_country] = new_city
    write_to_file(query_country, new_city)

root.mainloop()
```

at the 5th line of code there is a error of inconsistent use of spaces or tabs in indentation, for my program, i am a very basic python learner, so help will be needed, thank you so much

Comment: The error can't be more litteral than that: there is an error in the indentation. After your ` for line in file:` in the first line, you need to indent by a few spaces (usually 4). Python is very strict with indentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **a lot** of problems with this code, although I did not actually encounter the error you specified.

You shouldn't be using both tabs and spaces to indent code in the same program. The Python style guide discourages uses of tabs, and prefers using 4 spaces instead, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

I'll go through the problems that I did find.

You should be using indention here

```
    for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    country, city = line.split('/')
    the_world[country] = city4
```

would become

```
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        country, city = line.split('/')
        the_world[country] = city
```

Quotation marks do not go around function arguments

```
def write_to_file(' country_name, city_name):
```

would become

```
def write_to_file(country_name, city_name):
```

You need to put a colon after with statements, and you forgot to indent here as well. You also do not need the last quotation mark.

```
with open('capital_data.txt,' 'a') as file
file.write('\n' + country_name + '/' + city_name')
```

would become

```
with open('capital_data.txt,' 'a') as file:
    file.write('\n' + country_name + '/' + city_name')
```

There is a space in your variable name here

```
    query_ country = simpledialog.askstring('country', 'type the name of a country:')
```

would become

```
        query_country = simpledialog.askstring('country', 'type the name of a country:')
```

You yet again forgot indentation here,

```
if query_country in the_world:
result = the_world[query_country]
messagebox.showinfo ('answer',
                     'The capital city of ' + query_country + ' is ' + result + '!')
```

would be

```
    if query_country in the_world:
        result = the_world[query_country]
        messagebox.showinfo ('answer',
                             'The capital city of ' + query_country + ' is ' + result + '!')
```

Likewise here

```
else:
new_city = simpledialog.askstring('teach me',
                                      'i don\ 't know! ' +
                                      'what is the capital of ' +     query_country + '?')
```

would become

```
else:
    new_city = simpledialog.askstring('teach me',
                                      'i don\ 't know! ' +
                                      'what is the capital of ' +     query_country + '?')
```

Here, you attempt to escape your quotation mark using \, but instead escape the space which comes after it.

```
'i don\ 't know! ' +
```

should be

```
'i don\'t know! ' +
```

Here, you attempt to escape your quotation mark using \, but instead escape the space which comes after it.

```
'i don\ 't know! ' +
```

should be

```
'i don\'t know! ' +
```

The full working code is below

```
from tkinter import Tk, simpledialog, messagebox

def read_from_file():
    with open('capital_data.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            country, city = line.split('/')
            the_world[country] = city

def write_to_file(country_name, city_name):
    with open('capital_data.txt','a') as file:
        file.write('\n' + country_name + '/' + city_name)

print(' ask the expert - capital city of the world')
root = Tk ()
root.withdraw()
the_world = {}

read_from_file()

while True:
    query_country = simpledialog.askstring('country', 'type the name of a country:')

    if query_country in the_world:
        result = the_world[query_country]
        messagebox.showinfo ('answer',
                             'The capital city of ' + query_country + ' is ' + 
result + '!')
    else:
        new_city = simpledialog.askstring('teach me',
                                      'i don\'t know! ' +
                                      'what is the capital of ' +     
query_country + '?')
    the_world[query_country] = new_city
    write_to_file(query_country, new_city)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for fixing my problem with the code, like i said i was only a python beginner and barely could find any mistakes, once again, thank you so much, i checked and the code works perfectly fine, thanks to you, have a good day!

Comment: @KLMRoyalDutchAirlinesForR you're welcome :) if my answer fixed your problem could you accept it using the check mark next to it

Comment: hey i came back and now the code doesn't seem to work, im just letting you know just in case you didn't

Comment: @KLMRoyalDutchAirlinesForR I suggest asking another question explaining the problem you are having. Remember to include the full error message and code.

Comment: I am extremely sorry but i messed up, apparently the python installer i used went corrupt and i had to reinstall it, and now it will work, thanks again

Comment: i also have another code that i have a problem with that i will need help to fix. ill post it right around now